# DQ542MA Driver proper settings for NEMA 17 Stepper Motor

Tags: diy-3d-printer, electronics, stepper, motor, stepper-driver

Using a 24 V power supply I have two NEMA 17 stepper motors each driven by a DQ542MA stepper motor driver. I have the current settings on the driver set for a RMS of 1.69 and a pulse/rev of 400. When I run the motors they run extremely well but become extremely hot. I need help to figure out what would be the proper settings to use in order to stop the overheating.

Attached is a photo of the motor's setting tables:

[image: Driver with current and REV tables]

Answer (score 2):

It is completely normal for a stepper motor to get hot. Taking [this datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/324/C140-A+datasheet.jpg) for example, specifies a 80 °C temperature *rise*. That is, in an room that is 25 °C ambient temperature, the motors would get up to 105 °C.

To prevent the motors from getting as hot you could further reduce the operating current, but likely the temperature they're running at is normal.

Comment: and add a cooler as well :)

Comment: @profesor79 That should not be necessary. Steppers are designed to run without active cooling.

Comment: agree. I just don't like to get burnt when touching stuff